# Why does "tf.constant(tf.random_normal((10, 4)))" cause an error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, initialization

In the following code, "a" works perfectly fine, and "c" also works. But "b" causes an error. Could someone explain the reason?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((10, 4)))
b = tf.constant(tf.random_normal((10, 4)))
c = tf.constant(np.random.randn(10, 4))
```

Comment: What error? Include the complete error trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also a new one who start using tensorflow. I believe that there is something wrong with your variable type. According to the tensorflow API, you should feed a constant or list of value to 'tf.constant()'. However, in you code, before you initialize the variables and run this session, 'tf.random_normal()' is something like a placeholder without any real meaning. You can try to run this code. I am not sure if I understand this problem and I would like to discuss with you.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.random_normal((10, 4))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    b = tf.constant(sess.run(a))
    print(sess.run(b))
```